# class_parents(): Class does not exist

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have the following hierarchy set up:

```
/src
    /application
        /models
            User.php, Item.php, etc.
   /config
        /mappings
            /yaml
                application.models.User.dcm.yml
```

The models are namespaced "application\models."  They all "use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM";  I'm using Doctrine's ClassLoader in my bootstrap.  These all seem to work.

Whenever I run the app, I get the following errors:

```
Warning: class_parents(): Class User does not exist and could not be loaded in /Library/WebServer/Documents/goodsam/library/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php on line 40

Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /Library/WebServer/Documents/goodsam/library/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php on line 257

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/goodsam/library/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php on line 257

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class User does not exist' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/goodsam/library/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/goodsam/library/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php(73): ReflectionClass->__construct('User')
#1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/goodsam/library/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php(867): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getClass('User')
#2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/goodsam/library/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(511): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->initializeReflection(Object(Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService))
#3 /Library/WebServer/Documents/goodsam/library/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(300): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->initializeReflection(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), Object(Doctrine\Comm in /Library/WebServer/Documents/goodsam/library/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php on line 73
```

---

First off, Doctrine says that the yaml mapping files must be fully qualified classnames.  Therefore, I named it to where it's pointing to the application\models directory.  However in the example docs, it looks like it wants full qualification to the mapping file itself?  Which one should this be?

Here is the top of my mapping file:

```
# application.models.User.dcm.yml
application\models\User:
```

If this looks right, any other clues on what might be broken?

Comment: Have you checked the ClassLoader models registration? Try to passing an absolut path: `$entitiesClassLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('models', 'full/path/to/models');`